# Custom filtering and grouping in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on functionality which allows users to create custom filters on specific models and store those results as a group. As a working example (imports omitted for brevity):

```
class Client(models.Model):
    email = CIEmailField()

class Activity(models.Model):
    client = BaseForeignKey("client.Client", null=True, related_name="logged_activities")
    employee = BaseForeignKey("business.Employee", null=True, related_name="logged_activities")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

We want to create filters which will group `Client`s on `Activity`s based on the creation time and associated `Employee` and store those results in a group to be used later. This is pretty straightforward task, except a user is allowed to modify the filter configuration and update fields on a `Client`, both of which may change whether or not a `Client` matches the filter criteria. (Note: in this example it's not possible updating a `Client` could change the result set, but future filters will.)

I'd like a many-to-many so we can easily get the groups a client is in, and conversely get the clients in a group, but it's not clear to me the best way to handle the filter configurations. This is currently supported in our system but the filters don't work correctly and the filter queries are run whenever information about a group needs to be used. Given that, as well as some other factors, we've decided to rebuild this functionality instead of attempting to refactor the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One crude way of handling it would be the following. You create a mapping or a hook that's key would match a field on the intermediate model on the many to many field. Then you register (add a key/value) for each of the various filters in the mapping/hook. You create your instances of the intermediate model with the appropriate keys. Then when you need to utilize a particular group's functionality, you pull the model instance out of the database, and use the key to find the particular filter functionality out the mapping/hook.

```
config_groups = {}

class BaseConfig:
    key = None # Must be overridden by subclasses
    # I assume each of your filters has some common interface.
    # Put that here and raise NotImplemented exceptions for each function.

class AFilterConfig(BaseConfig):
    key = 'a_filter'
    # Implement AFilter's specific filtering logic.

config_groups[AFilterConfig.key] = AFilterConfig

class ConfigGroup(models.Model):
    # Relationship fields to Client and/or Activity
    key = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, choices=list(config_groups.keys()))


def view_function(request):
    config_group = ConfigGroup.objects.get()
    filter_config = config_groups[config_group.key]
```

If you want to take it a step further you can look into making this mapping/hook an actual Django model field. Such that you would be able to do the following without having to deal with importing and indexing into the mapping/hook.

```
def view_function(request):
    config_group = ConfigGroup.objects.get()
    filter_config = config_groups.filter_config
```